# Is there a way to define a function such that the sets in the domain are the same size?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^a$, $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^b$ and $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^c$.

I would like to define a function $f$ that can take any subset of $A$, $B$ and $C$ and return a real value $x$, but the function is only defined when these subsets are the same size. What is the correct notation for doing this? My, slightly hacky, attempt is:
$$f:\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}^a) \times \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}^b) \times \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}^c) \to \mathbb{R},(A,B,C) \mapsto x,\ \text{where $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is the power set of $X$, and |A|=|B|=|C|}.$$
But I don't think this really addresses the fact that the sets in the domain need to be the same size. Is there any way to capture this in the notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did was almost the solution, you just have to translate mathematically what you wrote in words:
You introduce the set $$S = \{(A, B, C)\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^a)\times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^b)\times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^c) : |A| = |B| = |C|\}.$$
This is a well-defined set, and then your function would be a function $f\colon S\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah, awesome. I didn't think of doing that, but it makes perfect sense. Thanks!